# Dotnet restore hook script?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Is there a way to run a custom script when my NuGet package is restored by `dotnet restore` command (or if this happens as a part of `dotnet build`)?

I want to copy a file to the user's home dir if it's not yet there.

Basically, I want to replicate an NPM install hook with .NET Core's NuGet.

Comment: NuGet users probably don't know what an NPM install hook is. I don't. What do you want to do? NuGet packages can contain install/uninstall scripts, if that's what you mean

Comment: Do they run on `dotnet restore` or only on `dotnet add package`?

Comment: And now that I looked it up, what do you want it for? NuGet is a package manager, not a build tool. Looks like NPM uses hooks to do some of the same jobs a build tool would

Comment: That's definitely *not* the job of a NuGet package. I would be very, very, *very* annoyed if adding a package messed with my user profile folder (c:\Users\MyAccount\...). Besides, that would probably break in a build server when it tried to copy stuff to the build account's home folder

Comment: A NuGet package is used to deploy files to projects, in a way that allows easy versioning, building and deployment. Trying to modify a specific user's folders breaks all three. The %USERPROFILE% folder is *a specific user's* profile data, application data, documents etc. A NuGet package has no business modifying them. Running applications can store data for that user in the correct folder, eg  `My Documents` for document files, %APPDATA% for non-document data. `%USERPROFILE%` is well-known to the OS, gets backed up, replicated when the user logs in to another machine etc.

Comment: When a user installs my package, they know this will happen. Now, they do it manually. My question is if I can, not if I should.

Comment: It's not a matter if you should - you shouldn't and therefore, it looks like you no longer can since VS 2017. What do you want to do? NuGet is *not* an installer or app deployment tool. There are probably other ways to do this, eg using .NET Core global or local tools, if you want to deploy tools for use during build. By convention, you can deploy scripts and tool assemblies [to the `tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) folder which.